# Redirect and post from a Content Page

Tags: asp.net

I'm using this class to send some variables to an external application using post-method. You can check the full procedure ->[HERE](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37539/Redirect-and-POST-in-ASP-NET)<-

```
/// <summary>
/// POST data and Redirect to the specified url using the specified page.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="page">The page which will be the referrer page.</param>
/// <param name="destinationUrl">The destination Url to which
/// the post and redirection is occuring.</param>
/// <param name="data">The data should be posted.</param>
/// <Author>Samer Abu Rabie</Author>

public static void RedirectAndPOST(Page page, string destinationUrl, 
                                   NameValueCollection data)
{
//Prepare the Posting form
string strForm = PreparePOSTForm(destinationUrl, data);
//Add a literal control the specified page holding 
//the Post Form, this is to submit the Posting form with the request.
page.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(strForm));
}
        /// <summary>
        /// This method prepares an Html form which holds all data
        /// in hidden field in the addetion to form submitting script.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="url">The destination Url to which the post and redirection
        /// will occur, the Url can be in the same App or ouside the App.</param>
        /// <param name="data">A collection of data that
        /// will be posted to the destination Url.</param>
        /// <returns>Returns a string representation of the Posting form.</returns>
        /// <Author>Samer Abu Rabie</Author>

    private static String PreparePOSTForm(string url, NameValueCollection data)
    {
        //Set a name for the form
        string formID = "PostForm";
        //Build the form using the specified data to be posted.
        StringBuilder strForm = new StringBuilder();
        strForm.Append("<form id=\"" + formID + "\" name=\"" + 
                       formID + "\" action=\"" + url + 
                       "\" method=\"POST\">");

        foreach (string key in data)
        {
            strForm.Append("<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"" + key + 
                           "\" value=\"" + data[key] + "\">");
        }

        strForm.Append("</form>");
        //Build the JavaScript which will do the Posting operation.
        StringBuilder strScript = new StringBuilder();
        strScript.Append("<script language="'javascript'">");
        strScript.Append("var v" + formID + " = document." + 
                         formID + ";");
        strScript.Append("v" + formID + ".submit();");
        strScript.Append("</script>");
        //Return the form and the script concatenated.
        //(The order is important, Form then JavaScript)
        return strForm.ToString() + strScript.ToString();
    }
```

If I call the method from a simple WebForm everything works well, but if I try to do the same from a ContentPage inside a MasterPage nothing happens.

I tried to figure it out with very little success...any idea??

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what the issue is/was in that linked article about doing a `server-side` POST to some external application and then redirect. Perhaps it was some specific use case/scenario...

- If you simply want to POST to an external application from ASP.Net WebForms and "redirect" (not really an accurate term - aka "send the user to that 3rd party application) then consider [Button.PostBackUrl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.postbackurl(v=vs.110).aspx)
- The article actually mentions [`HttpWebRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`WebClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient(v=vs.110).aspx) and then (erroneously IMHO) ties that to wanting to "redirect" (if so then above `Button.PostBackUrl` suffice, unless I'm missing something). To use these methods means

  - you will send an HTTP Request, e.g. `POST` data to 3rd party application `server-side`
  - you will process the response from the 3rd party in *your application* (not "redirect")
  - do whatever you need to do with the data from the 3rd party application
  - decide what to do next:

    - render some result in your application, **or**;
    - do an HTTP Redirect if you so deem (perhaps because this action requires something from the response data you got *before* you redirect). A good example of this is `PayPal's Express Checkout` (classic API) where a `token` is returned to your application (from a server-side POST) which is then used in the redirect (to PayPal).

Additionally, it's "hackish" in the context of ASP.Net `WebForms` to "inject" a `<form/>` within another `<form/>` ([you can't nest forms](http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html3/forms.html)). The **entire** page in ASP.net WebForms is a `form`.

Yes, you can inject a `form` entirely via Javascript (and outside of the WebForm `form`), but given the above options, and unless there is some specific use case, it shouldn't be necessary.

Hth...

Answer (score 0):

As EdSF has said you really do not want to nest forms as it can cause issues. If you cannot use PostBackURL for some reason though you could just change your code a bit.

Step one would be to make sure you have an id for the from in your master page.
Step two would be to comment out any reference line using the strForm variable
Step three would be to change the foreach code block to read

```
foreach (string key in data)
{
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterHiddenField( key, data[key] );
}
```

and finally change the last line in the preparePOSTForm method to read

```
return strScript.ToString();
```

References

[Creating a hidden field in codebehind and accessing it via clientside javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24526713/creating-a-hidden-field-in-codebehind-and-accessing-it-via-clientside-javascript)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager.registerhiddenfield(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions, but I'm totally new to this and I still have some problems..

I gave an id to my form in my master page, I commented the lines you suggested, edited the last line in the preparePOSTForm and I changed the foreach, but it's still not working..I'm getting an error inside the foreach (An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property System.Web.UI.Page.ClientScript.get).

I don't really get it...

Comment: I would try to solve that issue using the solution proposed in this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11894219/does-page-clientscript-available-been-used-in-class-cs